# Create new git repo from already existing repo's subdirectory

Tags: git

I want to create a separate repo from an already existing repo's subfolder.

[Detach (move) subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository) shows exactly that. BUT, I can't get a clean repo with it. I end up with two problems with the new repo:

1. The history seems duplicated;
2. I can't keep the branches history.

Here is what I did:

```
$ git clone ssh://.../repo.git
$ cd repo
$ git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter subdirectory HEAD -- --all
$ git reset --hard
$ git gc --aggressive
$ git prune
```

After this, it seems I have the original history of the repo AND the new history. I type "git log **--all** --graph" (or gitk --all) I see, as the first commit, the initial commit of the first repo. The graph then shows the original repo's full history until the last commit. Then, I have a SECOND history on top of the first one showing the history of only the subfolder I want. But in that part of the history I only have "master" and no branches/merges.

"git log", gitk or gitg all show the "flatten" history only: they don't show the initial repo's history before the the subfolder's flatten history.

I tried using just the "filter-branch" command, cloning the resulting repo (with --no-hardlinks), using:

```
$ git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter subdirectory -- --all
```

instead of:

```
$ git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter subdirectory HEAD -- --all
```

But with the same result.

Am I am doing something wrong or git is broken? I'm really out of ideas... Using git 1.7.6. Thanks.

EDIT: I think the problem might come from the fact that merge commits are ignored by filter-branch, thus giving a flat history with no branches or merges...

Comment: Is the branch history there with `git branch -a`

Comment: No:
`$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master`

Answer (score 4):

You have two problems here:

(1) As Kevin Ballard points out, you need to delete the refs/original directory in your .git directory to get rid of the spurious log entries; IIRC this is mentioned in the question you referred to.

(2) You have to convert the branches one at a time. As far as I know, this isn't mentioned anywhere, but it's pretty easy to discover empirically. A script to do this would look something like this:

```
for branch in $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/remotes/origin | grep -v HEAD); do
  git checkout -b $(basename $branch) $branch
  git filter-branch -f --subdirectory-filter subdirectory HEAD -- --all
done
```

Note that you need the -f or else something like --original $(basename $branch)-original to force git to reuse or rename the namespace where it stores the original refs. Also note that you may see messages like "Found nothing to rewrite" if *subdirectory* does not exist on a particular branch -- you will probably want to delete those branches from your new repository. (Or delete them before running the script.)

Comment: Is there a way to automate the deletion if the filter-branch returns "Found nothing to write", by expanding your script somehow?

Answer (score 4):

Github has a straight forward method:

https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subpath-out-into-a-new-repository

1. Clone the full repo: `git clone https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY-NAME`
2. Go to the root of the repo: `cd REPOSITORY-NAME`
3. Filter out subfolder `A/B/C`: `git filter-repo --path A/B/C/`

   - install [`git-filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo): `pip install git-filter-repo` (or any other method)
   - Provide the path structure relative to the root
   - Use forward slashes, even on Windows (the path refers to a git object, not to a location on the file system)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to remove your remotes. e.g.

```
git remote rm origin
```

I thought the same thing you did when I ran `git log --all` and `gitk --all` and saw all the commits. Then I realized the extra commits were from the remote.

Answer (score 0):

`git filter-branch` saves all the original refs into their own namespace (under `original/`). It sounds like your `git log --all` is showing those refs too. You should instead inspect all the refs you care about, and if they look good, then you can throw away the `original/` namespace.