# Fork a file from a Git repository without cloning the repository

Tags: git

Is there a way to fork a file from a foreign Git repository without cloning the whole repository?

Comment: You need to clone, but then you can strip out all you don't want.

Comment: This is very close to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680709/create-new-git-repo-from-already-existing-repos-subdirectory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest you could get to doing this is by using [sparse checkout](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-read-tree.html#_sparse_checkout), which means using Git 1.7+ and you still need to clone the repo (or use [`clone`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-clone.html)'s `--depth` option to do a shallow clone). Borrowing largely from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2467629/649852), you could do the following:

```
git clone --no-checkout <URL to git repo> myrepo
cd myrepo
git config core.sparseCheckout true
vim .git/info/sparse-checkout # Add files you want checked out
git checkout <branch you want>
```

If you have Git version 1.7.7-rc0 or later, you can set configuration options with the `clone` command:

```
git clone --config core.sparseCheckout=true --no-checkout <URL to git repo> myrepo
```

Also, see the following:

- [Partial clone with Git and Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2587244/649852)
- [How to retrieve a single file from specific revision in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/610315/649852)
- [Sparse checkout in Git 1.7.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336580/sparse-checkout-in-git-1-7-0)
- [Is it possible to do a sparse checkout without checking out the whole repository first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114887/is-it-possible-to-do-a-sparse-checkout-without-checking-out-the-whole-repository)

Comment: thx, but somehow the first line results in "error: unknown option `config'"

Comment: The `clone` `--config` option is available beginning with Git 1.7.7-rc0. If you have a prior version, remove the `--config core.sparseCheckout=true` and after the `git clone` command, execute `git config core.sparseCheckout true`. But you will still need a version at least 1.7.0.

Answer (score -3):

Unlike Subversion, Git does not support partial checkouts.