# Fork files from multiple repositories in to a single package in git

Tags: git

Suppose I have repository A, repository B, and repository C. I want to create repository X, with some files from repositories A, B, and C. Is there a way I can fork files from multiple repositories into a single repository?

Also, if I have a CMakeLists.txt in each repository, but I only want one in my repository X, can I merge the three from repositories A, B, and C?

Comment: here is a good start point https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442818/fork-a-file-from-a-git-repository-without-cloning-the-repository

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fork a file from a Git repository without cloning the repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442818/fork-a-file-from-a-git-repository-without-cloning-the-repository)