# "Frankensteining" a fork from a git repository - allow merge-backs of moved files

Tags: git, version-control

I want to create a fork from the [Arduino repository](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino) in order to create standalone versions of the AVR core and libraries, but I want to:

1. isolate some of it such that only `libraries/` and `hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/` (moved to `core/`) are forked from the original repository, and
2. allow for merging back into as well as updating from the original repository.

I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442818/fork-file-from-git-repo-without-cloning-the-repo) and [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680709/create-new-git-repo-from-already-existing-repos-subdirectory) and [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository), but none of them seem to match the second requirement.

*I would also be interested in knowing how/if other tools can handle this, but seeing as how the source repository is git, that would be my tool of choice.*

Comment: The crux seems to be in how to deal with moved files, although that's only the tip once/if the branches start to really become disparate "part" bundles..

Comment: Deleting a bunch of files changes all the commit hashes, so at that point you're basically talking about having to roll-your-own push/pull tool based on the git patches (diff + message + metadata).  And it seems like to do that, you'd pretty much need to have a full clone of the original repository anyway, which seems like it mostly defeats the purpose of paring it down?  Why was it you wanted to do that again?

Answer (score 3):

What you want *is possible* but the synchronization of the two repos requires some work.

Any strategies involving `git-filter-branch` are not suitable here, since you lose the connection between the two repos by rewriting the fork's history.

To illustrate the basic principle of doing this, let's create a test repository

```
> git init merge-move-test && cd merge-move-test/
@master> echo "foo" > foo
@master> git add .
@master> git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

Next we create our fork that moves things around

```
@master> git checkout -b fork
@fork> git mv foo bar
@fork> git commit -m "Rename foo to bar"
@fork> git tag rename-commit
```

Shortly after your fork, a modification is made upstream

```
@master> echo "Upstream update" > foo
@master> git commit -am "Upstream update of foo"
```

At this point you can keep your fork up-to-date with master quite easily

```
@fork> git merge --no-edit master
```

That's it. Take a look at the diff, and you will see that the effect is exactly as intended

```
@fork> git diff HEAD^ HEAD
diff --git a/bar b/bar
index 257cc56..f7f3304 100644
--- a/bar
+++ b/bar
@@ -1 +1 @@
-foo
+Upstream update
```

At this point doing local development and merging upstream changes requires no special steps.

It gets interesting when you want to merge your changes back upstream. So suppose you introduce some *amazing* changes that *have* to be in `master`

```
@fork> echo "Improvement from fork" > bar
@fork> git commit -am "Improve bar in fork"
```

If you would just merge `fork` into `master` now, you would not only apply the content change to `foo`, but also rename `foo` to `bar`. That makes sense, since that is exactly the set of changes from `fork` that master hasn't seen yet.

So what we need to do, is tell `master` we don't want that piece of change. One way to do this is merge everything, then revert the unwanted changes. If you want to have everything in one commit, this would be the way to do it

```
@master> git merge --no-commit --no-ff fork
@master> git revert --no-commit rename-commit
@master> git commit -m "Merge improvement from fork"
```

Another way would be to first merge the unwanted changes using the strategy `ours` followed by the actual merge.

```
@master> git merge --no-edit -s ours rename-commit
@master> git merge --no-edit fork
```

[More information on excluding changes from a merge.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/727994/380229)

After you've done that, the situation is kind of reversed. You can now merge any amount of changes from `fork` into `master`, but trying to do the reverse will undo your initial renaming in `fork`, since that is part of the merge commit in `master`.

So every time you want to merge changes from `A` to `B`, have to make sure that these do not include the reversal of changes from `B` in `A`. If there are any such changes revert them using one of the methods above.

If you want to play around with the test repo, [here's a shell script that runs the above commands](https://gist.github.com/raphinesse/1e2fbcca61056e6fe60135eb6705957d).